# Unable to find image 'jmeter:latest' locally when the image is already available

Tags: docker, jmeter

I am trying to run JMeter in a docker container. To achieve this I initially pulled [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/egaillardon/jmeter) JMeter image from the docker hub. Then when I do

> docker image ls

It shows the pulled image
[image]

But when I execute the below command and try to run the container It gives me the below error:

```
export volume_path=/Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/jmeter_resource && export jmeter_path=/jmeter && docker run --rm --name jmeterContainer --memory="512m" --cpus=2 --volume ${volume_path}:${jmeter_path} -e JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512 -Xmx512" jmeter -t ${jmeter_path}/factorial.jmx -l ${jmeter_path}/jmeter_results.jtl -q ${jmeter_path}/user.properties  egaillardon/jmeter:latest
```

> Unable to find image 'jmeter:latest' locally docker: Error response
>   from daemon: pull access denied for jmeter, repository does not exist
>   or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the
>   resource is denied. See 'docker run --help'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from here :

```sh
docker run --rm --name jmeterContainer --memory="512m" --cpus=2 --volume ${volume_path}:${jmeter_path} -e JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512 -Xmx512" jmeter ...
```

At this point you have `jmeter` in the command and it is interpreted as the image `jmeter:latest`. The rest of your command will just override your docker image `CMD`.

That is why the error is referencing image `jmeter:latest` and not `egaillardon/jmeter:latest`

Answer (score 0):

What @Marc mentioned was the problem but since a solution was not mentioned I'm posting how I solved it for future reference. My problem was that I have put the image tag in the wrong place. The working command is as shown below:

```
export volume_path=/Users/sulekahelmini/Documents/fyp/fyp_work/MLscripts/jmeter_resource && export jmeter_path=/jmeter && docker run --rm --name jmeterContainer --memory='512m' --cpus=2 -e JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512 -Xmx512" --volume ${volume_path}:${jmeter_path} egaillardon/jmeter --nongui -t factorial.jmx -l jmeter_results.jtl -q user.properties
```